# How to reset add-on preferences?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, customization

I'm surprised that I can not find an answer to this one. Is there any way to restore a specific add-on's *preference states* to the defaults?

*I would prefer not to uninstall the add-on if possible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an *Operator* and make it part of the *Preferences layout* for your **custom add-on**:

```
class MyAddonPreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):

    bl_idname = __name__

    display_flag: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
            name="Display Flag",
            default = True)

    def draw(self, context):
          ...
          layout.row().operator("my_addon.reset_preferences")
```

Best practice is using [`property_unset(property)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=property_unset#bpy.types.bpy_struct.property_unset):

```
class MYADDON_OT_resetPreferences(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ Reset Add-on Preferences """
    bl_idname = "my_addon.reset_preferences"
    bl_label = "Reset Properties and Settings"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}

    def execute(self, context):
        prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        prefs.property_unset("display_flag")
        ...
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

---

In order to reset the properties of a **certain add-on** it's basically the same, you just need to find a way getting the name of each property.

Example on how to reset the settings of *Loop Tools* by reading its annotations using the *Console*:

```
>>> prefs = C.preferences.addons['mesh_looptools'].preferences
>>> props = prefs.__annotations__.keys()
>>> for p in props:
...     prefs.property_unset(p)
```

Comment: So essentially call property_unset() for each preference variable? This is really useful, thank you. What about from a user's perspective - a user wanting to clear an add-on's preferences without scripting? I haven't experimented much with this, but how would they usually go about doing this? Is there a folder or file where these settings are saved per-project? Thanks again!

Comment: There is no generic option for the user atm, you have to provide that @Robert