# Add-on Dev: How to iterate the properties of a type and read/write values

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm wanting to iterate properties and get/set values. Example code:

```
for prop in self.rna_type.properties.keys():

    # get property name
    name = str( prop )

    # skip properties if first ident character is lower case (auto added properties)
    if name[0].islower():
        continue

    # assign new value
    self[name] = value
```

**Edit note:** There was no need for me to convert `prop` into a string with `str()` at the top of this loop. All elements inside of `keys()` are identifier strings.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you could simply iterate through all properties and check if their values are of type bool. If they are, then set them to the desired value.

Comment: @rjg: Yeah, that's what I'm after. I'm just not sure how to use that object/list. I'm currently trying to use `dir()` to figure it out, but looking for any type of information about dealing with them. Primarily what each member variable represents.

Comment: Annotations? Suggested here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152816/31447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the annotations to get and set each prop.

```
>>> settings = C.scene.my_addon
>>> settings.__annotations__.keys()
>>> for p in settings.__annotations__.keys():
...     getattr(settings, p)
...     setattr(settings, p, True)
```

Comment: Think I'm finally starting to understand how some of this works. So `keys()` is just a list of property identifier strings. `values()` is a list property values, and `items()` is sort of a combination of both. When you showed me `__annotations__` before, I assumed it was some component specific to Blender's preference class. A specific nested type. That's on me, sorry. Also appreciate the usage example.

Comment: Glad I could help @Robert Yep, `keys()` returns the keys and `values()` the values of an usual *key-value pair* (aka dict).